# Iframe autoplay video is not working first time

Tags: php, html, jquery, iframe

I have created a php code to autoplay video with sound using iframe.It's only working in chrome.
when i open link first time iframe is not loading video with autoplay but when i refresh the page video is loading with autoplay and sound. Below is my iframe code.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/439165184?api=1;title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=d01e2f&autoplay=1&controls=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" loop="1" controls="1" allowfullscreen allow=autoplay></iframe>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Share your code, please

Comment: i used above iframe tag code. It works when we hard refresh the page but not working first time. @Belegnar

Comment: I mean the same. Something is wrong with source page (or headers)